# Get CustomProperty value of taxonomy

Tags: c#, asp.net, taxonomy, ektron

I assigned Custom property to Taxonomy.I need to get the custom property value by passing **Taxonomy Id** by using programmaticaly with Ektron Framework Api.

I worked in Ektron 9.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve Taxonomy Custom properties by using the `CustomPropertyObject` class. I use a code similar to this one:

```
var customApi = new CustomPropertyObject();
var customPropertyId = 0;  // Put here your custom property id
var taxonomyId = 0;        // Put here your taxonomy Id

var customProperties = customApi.GetItem(taxonomyId, 2057 /* language code */,
    EkEnumeration.CustomPropertyObjectType.TaxonomyNode, customPropertyId)
        .Items.ToDictionary(i => i.PropertyId, i => i.PropertyValue.ToString());
```

You just need to put your own `TaxonomyId`, `CustomPropertyID` and language code.

Hope this helps,
Jonatan